# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable al ejecutar un bucle

Tags: python

estoy intentando insertar un mismo registro de una tabla (t1) n veces sobre otra tabla (t2) donde n seria el valor obtenido de uno de los campos de t1, por ejemplo campo: nro_unidades con el valor: 10, por lo que si del primer registro el campo nro_unidades es igual a 10  y del segundo registro el campo nro_unidades es 20 y asi con todo los registros de la tabla t1, el resultado en t2 seria 10 registros iguales + los siguientes 20 registros iguales, etc. (espero se me entienda)

en la salida obtengo esto:

```
(1, 2, 73, 363420.0, 50, 31, 17, 2, 0, 0, 2954.6341463414633, 3, 2, 2, 1)
50
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

ahora bien solo funciona para el primer registro y cuando completa el insert sale el error y no llega
a procesar el siguiente registro y sale el error.

aqui el codigo que tengo, uso mysql y el codigo python lo estoy ejecutando en un Colab notebooks:

```
try:
mariadb_conexion = mariadb.connect(
    host=host_ip, 
    port=nro_port, 
    user=username, 
    password=password, 
    database=database
    )

tablename = 'Detalle_T1_Granu'

cursor = mariadb_conexion.cursor(buffered=True)

#cursor.execute('truncate table Detalle_T1_Granu')

cursor.execute('select * from T_Detalle_T1')

mariadb_conexion.autocommit = False

while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row == None:
        break
    print(row)
    print(row[4])
    cant = row[4]
    if cant > 0:
        n = 0
        while n < cant:
            n += 1
            query = """
                INSERT INTO Detalle_T1_Granu (
                    NRO_ENCUESTA,
                    TIPO_UNIDAD,
                    AREA_X_UNIDAD,
                    PRECIO_SOLES,
                    NRO_UNIDADES,
                    UNIDADES_A,
                    UNIDADES_B,
                    UNIDADES_C,
                    ARRENDAR,
                    USO_PROPIO,
                    PRECIO_X_M2,
                    NRO_DORMITORIOS,
                    NRO_BANIOS,
                    PARA_SERVICIO,
                    TIPO_INTEGRACION_COCINA
                )
                VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
            cursor.execute(query, row)
    elif cant == 0:
        qury = """
            INSERT INTO Detalle_T1_Granu (
                NRO_ENCUESTA,
                TIPO_UNIDAD,
                AREA_X_UNIDAD,
                PRECIO_SOLES,
                NRO_UNIDADES,
                UNIDADES_A,
                UNIDADES_B,
                UNIDADES_C,
                ARRENDAR,
                USO_PROPIO,
                PRECIO_X_M2,
                NRO_DORMITORIOS,
                NRO_BANIOS,
                PARA_SERVICIO,
                TIPO_INTEGRACION_COCINA
            )
            VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        cursor.execute(qury, row)

    mariadb_conexion.close()
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
    #print("handled successfully")
```

Comment: Después del _insert_, el `cursor` cambia y queda vacío, por eso no te funciona. Deberías guardar primero todas las filas antes de empezar con los _inserts_. Usa `cursor.fechall()`.